# com.jcraft.jsch.jschexception connection is closed by foreign host

Tags: java, linux, ssh, jsch

I am trying to connect to a server to execute a shell script file. But sometimes, it connects & most of time it gives below exception:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.jschexception connection is closed by foreign host
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:269)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
```

I think If there is an issue with whitelisting then it should never connect.

Can you please help?

Comment: I'm not usre what you're polling.. but some sites will ban you if you call them too many times in a certain time period.

Did you make lots of calls?

Comment: No, i don't think we made lots of calls. We just made few calls & there was no pattern to find when this may work & may not. For eg: out of 6 calls today, it worked only once (without changing anything). Similar experience yesterday.

Comment: Maybe you have latency issues? Can you ping to see if the latency is good?
Maybe you're timing out?

do you see this problem if you try to connect by other means?

It might help to see what your code is doing to have a little context. It could be that your code just takes too long at times and the connection dies?

Comment: will try this. Thank you :)

Comment: is it a docker host you are connecting to? I got similar issues, when docker network changes on the host